# find the equation of the diameter which passes through the origin.

Tags: circles, quadratics

I am given the equation of the circle $x^2+y^2−4x+6y=14$, and I am told to  find the equation of the diameter which passes through the origin.
However, I am unsure as to how to do this.

Comment: Every diameter passes through the center of the circle.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2+y^2-4x+6y=14$$
$$x^2-4x+4-4+y^2+6y+9-9=14$$
$$(x-2)^2+(y+3)^2=27$$

Hence the center of the circle is $(2,-3)$.

You just have to find the equation of a straight line that connects the origin and the center of the circle.